# GraphicsMagick getting "Stream yields empty buffer error" on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, graphicsmagick

I am using GM for very simple thing: drawing a circle and put it in buffer. But after I check the code into Elastic Beanstalk, I am getting the "Stream yields empty buffer error" error. I am not sure why because it totally works on localhost.

Here is the code:

```
gm(200, 200, '#FF0000')
        .setFormat('png')
        .fill('#00FF00')
        .drawCircle( 50, 50, 60, 60 )
        .toBuffer(function( error, buffer )
        {
            if( error ) { res.send("error:"+error+" with content length:"+data.ContentLength);}
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
               res.end(buffer, 'binary');
        }
```

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**
I ran: gm convert -list format on both local and EC2 and found out that EC2 are missing PNG and JPEG support on it. Wondering how can I add the support. Any clues?

Comment: A black circle on a black background was never going to amount to much - least of all when you encode it as a PNG and tell the browser a GIF is coming ;-)

Comment: :-)  Thank you for pointing it out. The response code was copied from the real production code. But it was giving the same error. So I used a simple gm initialization to see what was the problem. But that shouldn't cause the buffer error, right?

Comment: Just for kicks, can you try setting the background to something like "#FF0000` and the fill to `#00FF00`?

Comment: Edited! Now the color is not black on black

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. Ran gm version command. Found out that PNG and JPEG are not supported. So turned out to be a dependency issue. Reinstall and solved it.

Comment: @Rougher You open a **Terminal** window (on a Mac) and enter `gm version` in the command line. It will display the output which includes the version as well as supported file types. You may need to scroll up in the window in order to see this information.