# Error: Stream yields empty buffer only on EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, imagemagick, buffer, jpeg

Is's my code that works on localhost, but not on EC2 (I used Elastic BeanStalk). I get error: **Stream yields empty buffer** on **toBuffer** function. Can somebody explain how to fix it? I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254454/graphicsmagick-getting-stream-yields-empty-buffer-error-on-elastic-beanstalk), but I didn't understand how to add JPEG support in EC2.

```
var _45px = { width: 45, dstnKey: fileName, destinationPath: "thumbnails" };
function convert(response, next) {
        console.time("convertImage");
        console.log("Reponse content type : " + response.ContentType);
        console.log("Conversion");
        GM(response.Body, fullName).antialias(true).density(300).setFormat('jpeg').toBuffer(
            function(err, buffer) {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                } else {
                    console.timeEnd("convertImage");
                    next(null, buffer);
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced a similar problem with PNG format. The problem arises because EC2 instances does not have support for PNG and JPEG, so we need to install the required dependencies accordingly, else the imagemagick (or graphicmagick) does not return any stream value as output.

For adding PNG support I have tried uninstalling graphicsmagick module and then installed the dependencies and reinstalled graphicsmagick:

apt-get install libpng-dev,
apt-get install graphicsmagick
(In your case this would be imagemagick)

This solved the problem. I believe for jpeg support the library would be:
libjpeg-dev.

These are for EC2 ubuntu instances